# got error invalid signature when requesting token

Tags: iphone

When am trying to request token for tripit oauth, I got the error invalid signature. 
My url is:

> https://api.tripit.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=c5676701706473430d016ac7dc58a0149333349e&oauth_consumer_secret=90b7567665605fad847815949ce414f7078742d5&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1304072442&oauth_nonce=kllo9940pd9333jh&oauth_version=1.0

Please help me, where I am wrong ???

Answer (score 0):

```
https://api.tripit.com/oauth/request_token?
oauth_consumer_key     = c5676701706473430d016ac7dc58a0149333349e&
oauth_consumer_secret  = 90b7567665605fad847815949ce414f7078742d5&
oauth_signature_method = HMAC-SHA1&
oauth_timestamp        = 1304072442&
oauth_nonce            = kllo9940pd9333jh&
oauth_version          = 1.0
```

I guess you are in the Temporary Credentials step. This *looks* all kinds of wrong. You shouldn't send `oauth_consumer_secret` which is not even a spec parameter, you are not sending a `oauth_callback`, you are not sending an `oauth_signature`, and you are sending a GET instead a POST (or at least you are not providing your POST data, which you can get from Safari or Firefox+Firebug/liveHttpHeaders), which unless the server says otherwise (which could be the case, I don't know) is wrong. Anyway, the answer is in the RFC, which I spent a few days reading and now it's fading from my memory.

You should try to use a library, or re-read rfc5849.
Only if you want to *understand* OAuth, I suggest you *read* my oauth client: https://github.com/j4n0/oauth because it is an implementation easy to follow.